# Why I cannot declare obj class as public?

Tags: java

I'm trying to declare obj class as public but it says `class obj is public should be declared in a file named obj.java`.

```
public class obj {

    String name; 

    public void show() {
        System.out.println (name );
    }
}

public class objects {

    public static void main (String args[]){
        obj object 1=new obj ();
        object1.name="sam"; 
        object1.show();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The answer is in your question. Your file is not called obj.java. Have your classes in separate files: obj.java and objects.java.

By the way, the java convention is to start class names with uppercase, e.g. Obj instead of obj. Also, you probably want to pick more descriptive names.

Comment: @user187744: Right: You're only allowed to have one public top-level class in a .java file, and the name of that class must match the filename. But you can have as many *non*-public classes in the file as you want.

Comment: without a qualifier a class is package-private. public classes must be in separate files named as the class

Comment: Please be aware that putting multiple *top-level* classes in a single `.java` file is **strongly** discouraged. Always put top-level classes in their own `.java` file.

Answer (score 3):

You should create **two** different files, `obj.java` and `objects.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what do you think that means? Follow Java naming conventions, please. Call it `Obj`, with a capital O. The problem is that the first class in a .java file (though I *highly* recommend you never put any more classes in a file than one), if it is `public`, **must** have the same name as the file (but without .java). Create a file called Obj.java with a class `Obj` and a file called Objects.java with a class `Objects`.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove public keyword from obj as you cannot have two public class in the same file.